# How can I concatenate cells in each row with a google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I was wondering how I can concatenate each row into one cell with symbols inbetween. Being that I have nearly 12000 rows with 1 address per row, it would be too time-consuming to do it manually with the concatenate function so is there a script that would loop through each row to join each column together?

Example: for row 1 in the picture, I am hoping for a result of "123 abc st., New York City, New York, USA, 12345" in F2 and so on for each row.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you want.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A1:A="","",(A1:A & ", " & B1:B & ", " & C1:C & ", " & D1:D & ", " & E1:E )))
```

Let me know if it doesn't do what you need.

Comment: oh my god, thank you so much. I'm not very familiar with Google Sheets so I was struggling with this for some time. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show a new line so address stacks  Name '\n' number " " street '\n" etc. I cannot get it with + or & or CONCAT